# How to initialize an interface that has type aguments of the type of another Interface

Tags: c#

ive run into a problem - these is my class structure

```
public interface IModel{}

public interface IGenericMapper<T> where T : IModel {...}

public class ActualModel:IModel {...}

public class ActualMapper: IGenericMapper<ActualModel> {...}
```

My actual code to initialse the mapper is:

```
IGenericMapper<IModel> mapper;
mapper= new ActualMapper();
```

It does not compile. I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ActualMapper' to 'IGenericMapper'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

When I do cast it using

```
mapper= new ActualMapper() as IGenericMapper<IModel>;
```

the mapper does not get initialized properly (it comes back as NULL)

What am I missing - since `ActualMapper()` implements `IGeneric` Mapper and its type impliments `IModel' why can it not initialize mapper.

Is there another way to structure this so achieve what I need?

Thank you so much

Note the  solution people have proposed gives me other compilation errors as the mapping Interface has the following members

```
T GetModel(busO bBusinessObject);
busO  SetBusObject(T source, busO  target);
```

apparently you cant have the generic type as an input parameter when its declared at "out"

Comment: can you add the definition of ILFFMapper<> ?

Comment: `var ILFFMapper<IModel>` it's a syntax error, remove `var` keyword

Comment: You need a covarient type. try IGenericMapper< out T>

Comment: `ActualMapper` is `IGenericMapper<ActualModel>` not `IGenericMapper<IModel>` hence results in null

Comment: sorry I was converting my actual code into generic code for the question - fixed

Comment: @gfdoomchicken Welcome to covariance; if you want to be able to change cast a higher derived `T` Type down to a base `TBase` then it has to be `out T` and you _cannot_ use it as an input. Like I said; its a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure you're moving into the realm of covarience here with the Generic change;

try this:

```
public interface IModel{}
public interface IGenericMapper< out T> where T : IModel{}
public class ActualModel : IModel{}
public class ActualMapper : IGenericMapper<ActualModel>   {}
```

and then:

```
IGenericMapper<IModel> blah = new ActualMapper();
```

with out the 'out T' the best you can do is:

```
IGenericMapper<ActualModel> blah = new ActualMapper();
```

This is a rabbit hole, so be careful especially if you ever try to mix the two  :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

**[Edit]**

If you want to be able to downcast the generic `T`, then it has to be `out` and you cannot use it as an input. You can, however, move some of it to *real time* in your implementation; i.e. to a check to see if you can cast it to a model type.

```
interface IGenericMapper<out TModel, in TKeyOrIdent> 

TModel GetModel(TKeyOrIdent bBusinessObject);
void SetModel(object model, TKeyOrIdent target);
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to define

```
IGenericMapper<out T>
```

to support your scenario, but this applies other limitations.

Simply `IGenericMapper<IModel>` != `IGenericMapper<ActualModel>` even if `ActualModel : IModel`

In most scenarios it makes sense to have a base interface that isn't a generic. See `IList<T>` for example, it implements `IList`.

You can then choose on implementation to explicitly implement interface members. See `List<T>.GetEnumerator() : IEnumerable`

Do not use generics under the assumption that you can eliminate casting everywhere. I've tried it C# simply doesn't have the required features for this.

I would suggest an `IGenericMapper` interface as base interface for `IGenericMapper<T>` then do your generic code on `IGenericMapper` and finally (and at that point you already have the type) cast it back to the specific type.